# Failed to resolve: core Affected Modules: app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, butterknife

I'm using Android Studio 3.5.3 and my Gradle version is 5.4.1 .
After adding **butterknife** my project don't sync and it shows an error that is "Failed to resolve: core".

i added

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

in android tag in madule:app.

and also added butterknife dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'
}
```

as like as butterknife steps in https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

my build.gradle(module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation  'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'


}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

my build.gradle(project:My Application)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()      
        jcenter()


    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
       maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com"}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And This is my error code

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: core
Affected Modules: app
```

[my error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mufzs.png)

Comment: just a suggestion you can use android data binding and avoid butterKnife

Comment: @AsadAli  i searched  about my problem but i didn't find any solution :( . Did you have problem like mine?

Comment: is any : core word inside your gradle,setting.gradle... files?

Comment: Did you check if you are in offline mode?

Comment: @shadow i just have  `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0' `

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena yes i checked,i am in online Mode

Comment: OK then try to add butterKnife dependency from 'Project Structure'-->'Dependencies'-->'Libraries' where you can easily 'Google' search on ButterKnife. Also feel free to try the update suggestions there.

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena i try it but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Post your settings.gradle and app/build.gradle. Let us find the culprit.

Comment: @ShahrYarAkhteh no when i am using butterknife its working fine

Comment: Are you working on Ubantu Linux?

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena i have Mint Linux

Answer (score 0):

Try to add butterKnife dependency from 'Project Structure'-->'Dependencies'-->'Libraries' where you can easily 'Google' search on ButterKnife. Also feel free to try the update suggestions there.

Check other libraries as well. Try disable dependencies by commenting out till you get to the problem. It is hit and trial method, because things are uncertain.

If you can post your gradle files, might can help you out.

You can try invalidating cache and let us know if it works.

Suspicion is that there would have been a module called core that was deleted. Might be there is any symbol thats called core and does not have any definition that IDE is able to recognise.

Comment: i edit my post ,i have this code in android studio on another windows and its work fine but i dont know why it doesnt work on my linux :| .

Comment: You say that you tried with fresh project, and it is only not working on Linux. What is the OS version? Is it Ubantu. If not, try with it.

Comment: Uninstall Mint and install Ubantu. It is the best. Make sure you copy all the settings, softwares and projects to an external storage first.